# Adding constrains in simulated annealing algorithm in R

Tags: r, optimization, simulated-annealing

I have a script for a simulated annealing algorithm and want to restrict the search, in this case to an hypercube.

```
simulated_annealing <- function(func, s0, niter = 1, epsilon = 0.01) {
#   ##s=state, f=funcion, b=best, c=current, n=neighbour

  s_b <- s_c <- s_n <- s0
   f_b <- f_c <- f_n <- func(s_n)

   for (k in 1:niter) {     
     Temperatura <- (1 - epsilon)^k 
     s_n <- rnorm(2, s_c, 1)
     f_n <- func(s_n)
     if (f_n < f_c || runif(1, 0, 1) < exp(-(f_n - f_c) / Temperatura)) {
       s_c <- s_n
       f_c <- f_n
     }
     if (f_n < f_b) {
       s_b <- s_n
       f_b <- f_n         
     }
   return(list(iteraciones = niter, Mejor_valor = f_b, Mejor_estado = s_b))
 }}
```

You use it like this:

```
sol <- simulated_annealing(rastr, niter = 100, epsilon = 0.91, s0 = c(0, 2))
```

I want to add restriccitions to the search space so it only moves in the hypercube x_i=[-5.12,5.12], but I don't know how to start. I tried to using while but it stopped the function.

Please and Thanks

Comment: Could you post a complete function? Either you have more contents inside your function, or you forgot the closing curly brace ``}`` at the end. Also, could you give an example of the usage and the desired result you would like? Reproducible data would be nice. And tell us what you are wanting to "restrict."

Comment: Done. You can used with any function, it just search for optima. I'm testing it in Rastrigin, usually constricted to the hypercube mentioned, but I suck in R and don't know how to add such restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get to a solution, albeit kind of uncool. The finished script is as follows:

```
      simulated_annealing <- function(func, s0, niter = 1000, epsilon = 0.1) {
x_upper = 5.12
x_lower = -5.12
  # Inicializamos
  ## s simboliza estado
  ## f simboliza valor de la funcion
  ## b simboliza el mejor obtenido hasta ahora
  ## c simboliza el presente
  ## n simboliza vecino
  s_b <- s_c <- s_n <- s0
  f_b <- f_c <- f_n <- func(s_n)
  message("Iteracion\tMejor\tActual\tVecino\tTemperatura")
  message(sprintf("%i\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%.4f", 0L, f_b, f_c, f_n, 1000))

  for (k in 1:niter) {
    Temperatura <- (1 - epsilon)^k #Exponencial
    # Contemplamos un vecino aleatorio
    s_n <- rnorm(2, s_c, 1)
    f_n <- func(s_n)
while (f_n > x_upper | f_n < x_lower) {
  s_c <- s_c[! s_c %in% c(s_n)] ##THIS IS THE ADDED LINE
  s_n <- rnorm(2, s_c, 1)
  f_n <- func(s_n)
}
#     # Actualizamos el estado actual
    if (f_n < f_c || runif(1, 0, 1) < exp(-(f_n - f_c) / Temperatura)) {
      s_c <- s_n
      f_c <- f_n
    }
#     # Actualizamos el estado al mejor conseguido
    if (f_n < f_b) {
      s_b <- s_n
      f_b <- f_n
    }
    if (k %% 1000==0) {
    message(sprintf("%i\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%.4f", k, f_b, f_c, f_n, Temperatura))}
  }
  return(list(iteraciones = niter, Mejor_valor = f_b, Mejor_estado = s_b))
}
```